# Dynamic Memory Allocation using malloc

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, dereference

```
    # include<stdio.h> 
# include<stdlib.h> 
   
void fun(int *a) 
{ 
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
} 
   
int main() 
{ 
    int *p; 
    fun(p); 
    *p = 6; 
    printf("%d\n",*p); 
    return(0); 
}
```

Why is the above code not valid ? And why does it give a segmentation fault?

Comment: The (uninitialized) pointer value stored in `p` is passed _by value_ into `fun` where you allocate memory, store it and then `a` is popped off the stack, leaking that memory.  You then dereference the original (uninitialized) value `p` and try to store data there, which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: The code is valid, in the sense that it does not contain errors for which the standard requires a diagnostic.   It has undefined behaviour though because `fun(p)` does not change `p`  (the argument `a` is passed to `fun()` by value, so the assignment to `a` does not affect value of `p` passed by `main()`).   `p` is uninitialised, so assigning `*p = 6` gives undefined behaviour - and a compiler is not required to diagnose undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` is passed by-value itself, then any modification on itself in the function has nothing to do with the argument.

You can change it to pass-by-reference as

```
void fun(int *&a) 
{ 
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
}
```

BTW: In C++ better to use `new` (and `delete`), or don't use raw pointers from the beginning.